# Is visual studio 2012 supported on window 8 regular edition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is visual studio 2012 supported on window 8 regular edition? Or I need window 8 professional edition.

Comment: Assuming you have a license to both Windows 8 standard and Visual Studio 2012, you should be fine. If you want a free license for Visual Studio, you can use Express Edition for free. It is just missing some features of the full version.

Comment: Ahh good, we now have the wall of shame naming the idiots who thought Visual Studio was "general computing software" and not "tools used primarily for programming".  And you call yourselves .NET developers.  Really?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, I won't upvote it because it doesn't show research effort.  I did vote to reopen though, because this "on hold" reason is totally bogus.

Answer (score 4):

You should be just fine running Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 non-Professional.

The ["Platform Compatibility and System Requirements" page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility) says "Windows 8 (x86 and x64)", which includes Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro, and Windows 8 Enterprise, but not Windows 8 RT which runs only on ARM.

If you're worried, use one of the trials and see before buying.

Answer (score -2):

I think Visual Studio doesn't come on the same installation disk by the windows editions. 
- You have to buy it seperately
- Or use the free edition
- Or use open source development tools as e.g. Sharp Develop

Comment: he is talking about what version of Windows 8 is required to run VS2012.

Comment: Just misunderstood the question in this case.

Comment: And even this rule is not universal.  For example, [here Windows 8 and Visual Studio were distributed together, by Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/13/welcome-to-windows-8-the-developer-preview.aspx)

Comment: I wrote I think and not that this is a rule. But thanks for upvote again.